# Align NumberPicker Text to Left

Tags: android, android-layout, text, alignment, numberpicker

I am using custom string in NumberPicker. The problem is the text comes in center, while I want it to align to the Left.

I tried extracting the TextView and setting the gravity there, using the following code -

```
TextView npTextView = (TextView) numberPicker.getChildAt(1);
npTextView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

But it sets the gravity of selected Text only. The text which is in scrolling position, still comes at center.

Is there any way to align the text to left?

PS: I am using API Level 15.

Comment: Was there every a resolution to this problem? I am also seeking a solution...

Comment: Same here, the customization of the NumberPicker is a real pain

Answer (score 2):

Eight years have passed since the time when the question was asked, so you could have +8 years of Android experience and may be capable of developing the desired number picker yourself :)

Whatever, I've encountered a similar problem and [upgraded Android NumberPicker to fulfill my needs](https://gist.github.com/Miha-x64/c9f473b7095f0c1dac6c36c18bde5b77). The original NumberPicker is far from perfect, so is mine, but after some tuning it worked for me.

Usage example:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View = LinearLayout(requireContext()).apply {
    isBaselineAligned = false

    val divider = ColorDrawable(0xFFDBDBDB.toInt()).apply {
        // share drawable, don't mind Callback, invalidation etc
        setBounds(0, 0, 0, dp2Px(context, 1)) // 1dp dividers
    }
    val pad = dp2Px(context, 16)
    val selectorWheelPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.roboto_light)
        textSize = sp(22f)
    }
    val scaleI = TimeInterpolator { cos(3.1415926535897932384f / 2f * it) }
    val alphaI = TimeInterpolator { cos(3.1415926535897932384f / 1.5f * it) }

    val cmPicker = FlexibleNumberPicker(context).apply {
        minValue = 0
        maxValue = 1000 // 10 metres is enough, I hope
        value = valueMm / 100
        setup(divider, selectorWheelPaint, scaleI, alphaI)
        setPadding(0, 0, pad, 0)
        val cm = resources.getString(R.string.cm)
        setFormatter { cm.format(it.toFloat()) }
        wrapSelectorWheel = false
        setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)
    }
    addView(cmPicker, LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, WRAP_CONTENT, 1f))

    addView(FlexibleNumberPicker(context).apply {
        minValue = 0
        maxValue = 9
        value = valueMm % 100
        setup(divider, selectorWheelPaint, scaleI, alphaI)
        setPadding(pad, 0, 0, 0)
        val mm = resources.getString(R.string.mm)
        setFormatter { mm.format(it.toFloat()) }
        setOnValueChangedListener(cmPicker.fractionListener)
        setGravity(Gravity.LEFT)
    }, LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, WRAP_CONTENT, 1f))
}

private fun FlexibleNumberPicker.setup(
    divider: ColorDrawable, paint: Paint,
    scaleI: TimeInterpolator, alphaI: TimeInterpolator,
) {
    setSelectionDivider(divider)
    setSelectorWheelPaint(paint)
    setWheelItemCount(5)
    setDividerOffset(.33f)
    setLineHeight(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 27f)
    solidColor = Color.WHITE
    setScaleInterpolator(scaleI)
    setAlphaInterpolator(alphaI)
}

val FlexibleNumberPicker.fractionListener: FlexibleNumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener
    get() = FlexibleNumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener { picker, oldVal, newVal ->
        val min = picker.minValue
        val max = picker.maxValue
        when {
            oldVal == min && newVal == max -> changeValueByOne(false)
            oldVal == max && newVal == min -> changeValueByOne(true)
        }
    }
```

[image: Sample render]

Comment: FYI, I left Android Development already ;-) 
Thanks for your effort anyway, I'll wait for the usual validation from the community before I accept it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can't be sure that 2nd child of NumberPicker is the right TextView because implementation of NumberPicker in different APIs is different. Try this code instead.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numberPicker.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = numberPicker.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) child).setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It's almost similar to my code, except that it puts the check to be sure. Only the selected Text gets left aligned, that too when scrolling animation has stopped, rest all stay in the center.